# Angular CLI installation error in ubunu - I have get an error when I am trying to run angular CLI command in my ubuntu machine

Tags: javascript, angular, ubuntu, npm-install, ubuntu-18.04

This error I have got.
I am already install node js and npm in my system.
I also have remove npm cache.

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2020-11-03T18_21_04_293Z-debug.log
~~~
```

Comment: The problem is obvious: `EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'`.  I'd recommend repeating the command with [sudo](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sudo-command-in-linux-with-examples/), if possible.  Otherwise, if you cannot get "root" privileges, you can always install npm packages locally: https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-packages-locally

Comment: You should probably install the npm packages locally and not run as root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `sudo` for this problem. Use `sudo` the way it is intended to be used in Ubuntu: for each command that requires it, no more. Don't use `sudo` to run a command unless it needs to be root. For example, most users would only need `sudo` for installing things.

Have you try, [manually change npm's default directory](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally#manually-change-npms-default-directory)?

```
mkdir ~/.npm-global
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
source ~/.profile
```

To test your new configuration, install a package globally without using `sudo`:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```